# Please help to find the name of the font

Tags: fonts

I need to find the exact name of this font:
[image]

I've tried different services like https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/, http://www.identifont.com/ and http://www.fontspring.com/matcherator

They all show different results and they do not match (((
Please help to find out what is the name of this font. This pic is the only one I've got.
Thanx!

Comment: There is probably a Preference setting on one of the menus (Edit?) in your application that allows you to set the font used. Have a look there and see what it is set to.

Comment: This is just a pic from internet

Comment: Good luck then ;) In any case your question is off-topic.

Comment: I know it was just my last hope((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely off-topic, but intriguing question. I looked up [the site where you got the picture from](http://www.increasinglyadequate.com/), where I learned that the creator of the picture [uses an old Mac](http://www.increasinglyadequate.com/images/screenshots/macwww.png). This lead me to look at [history of Mac fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonts_on_Macintosh#Fonts_of_the_original_Macintosh). Your font sort-of looks like the original Chcago font, but that not exactly it. By accident, I stumbled upon the [Terminus font](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/), which [at 16px](http://www.lowing.org/fonts/images/showPreview.php?filter=ter-116n.gif) is exactly what you're looking for.

[image: Terminus 16px font]